# Find all functions and classes involved in the output of a given function f?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Let's say I have a function f:

```
def f():
    ...
```

Is there a simple way to find all functions (source code + path) and classes (source code + path) involved in the output of `f`? For example if `f` used an imported function `g`, to compute its output, can we get the source `g` + its path?

Perhaps the python `ast` or `dis` library is capable of doing this elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

No, because that information is only available when `f` is executed. Suppose you have the following `f`:

```
def f(x):
    return x.text()
```

What type is `x`? What's `text`? Who knows! `f` doesn't include any of that information.

---

If you're actually *executing* `f`, you can find out what functions `f` relied on for a particular execution. For example, using a profiler, you could do

```
import cProfile
cProfile.runcall(f, x)
```

to profile the execution of `f(x)` and see what gets called. If you need more information, you could probably build something based on the `profile` module to gather the data. This still won't get you any information about what `f` would have called in situations you didn't test, though.

Comment: Could we inspect `x`, and get the class definition that created `x`, return the source lines of that class definition + path (which is the ideal answer for the `f` you wrote)? I.e. couldn't we use something like `ast` to jump into `x`?

Comment: @applecider: No, because you have no `x`. You could get that kind of information by profiling the execution of a program that uses `f`, but that requires you to actually execute it.

Comment: ahh I see, I am okay with executing it, could we achieve a solution like that? I guess one thing that comes to mind is a step by step debugger, which would let you step into `x.text()` which would take you to the source code of the `text` method on whatever class produced `x`. If we could do that recursively and return all source and file paths visited, that would be the solution I think.

Comment: If you can "interpret" python at runtime, you can interpret it at analysis time too, so in principle you can extract this information, modulo the Turing tarpit.  I beleive Python has "eval" which is famously hard to interpret (especially if it gets its argument from the keyboard or someplace else outside the program),  and then of course there is the potential for impossible-to-untangle condition which may or may not load a file.   Ignoring these cases, one can probably build a tool that gives a pretty good approximation of the answer.   It is probably a lot of work to do it; AST isn't enough.

Comment: @IraBaxter: You still need both `f` and its arguments to do that, and you end up needing to pretty much simulate the whole execution of `f` to get even pretty simple things like `sorted(l, key=methodcaller('foo'))` right. Also, it's hard to introspect what any components written in C do without actually running them.

Comment: @user2357112: Yep, you need everything you would need to "interpret" the code at runtime in the worst case.    You can make assumptions (producing perhaps incorrect but useful answers) where you decide to leave someting out or approximate its effect.  That still gets you a static analysis.